# Who is "them" in Lake's dialogue?

Tags: planet-of-the-apes, war-for-the-planet-of-the-apes, planet-of-the-apes-2011

In *War for the Planet of the Apes* (2017), After Caesar gets arrested by the Colonel's soldiers, Lake said the following words to Caesar in prison:

> Caswer: Lake...
>
> Lake: Forgive **them**. We've been through much.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site.

Comment: Forgive them, they know not what they do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Apes

<sub>Starting with saying that I can't provide you with the video yet but will try and remember to add it in later.</sub>

Lake is asking Caesar to forgive the Apes as when he's thrown into the cage and beat, the other apes turn away and shun him. This is likely because Caesar insisted on them leaving their "city" and moving to the oasis across "The Desert" however in doing so they were captured by the Colonel and locked up and put into forced labour where they were starved while he was "supposedly" hunting down the Colonel.

Whether or not this is supposed to reflect Catholicism and the need to forgive those who have sinned against one is not one I can personally state was intended.

Comment: How 'bout that video now? :)